# React-router-dom sending props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem sending props using react-router-dom. I'm getting this error:

> Matched leaf route at location `"/"` does not have an element. This
> means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value by default
> resulting in an "empty" page."

```js
<Routes>
  <Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={routeProps => (
  <ProductList
    {...routeProps}
    products={this.state.products}
    addToCart={this.addToCart}
    currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory}
    info={productInfo}
  />
  )}
  />
  <Route exact path="/cart" element={<CartList />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Btw "/cart" and "not found" routes are running, No problem from there.

Comment: Those routes work because you _do_ have an `element=`; as the error tells you, the route that _isn't_ working _"does not have an element"_. Read https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5.

Comment: So my question is how can I add element in "/" route. Because I'm sending props.. I read that link before but it didnt solve my problem.

Comment: It _does_ solve your problem. You no longer access the route props that way, the migration docs tell you how to do it in v6.

Comment: RRDv6 `Route` components no longer have a `render` prop, or route props. The error is telling you there is no `element` prop for the `"/"` route. The `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, so you can pass all the props you need like you already are ***other than*** any route props since they don't exist.